# Why self.window ,why not use _window

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7

```
@interface Student
{
    UIWindow* _window;
}
@property (weak,readwrite) UIWindow *window;
@end

#import "Student.h"
@implementation Student
@synthesize window;

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];//here why self.window ,why not use _window

     [_window makeKeyAndVisible];  
}
```

Here, why self.window ,why not use _window ._window also contain the *window then why we are not using _window to make a call of makeKeyAndVisible message on that _window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code: (Objective-C) 
@synthesize window=_window;

it says to synthesize getters and setters for the property named window and to associate that property with an instance variable called _window (which does not have to be separately declared elsewhere).  Apple wants you to set and retrieve the value of the instance variable through the synthesized setters and getters.  That is, writing something like this:

Code: (Objective-C) 
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

will fail, as there is no instance variable named window.  Instead, you have to either name the instance variable directly by its name; i.e.,

Code: (Objective-C) 
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];

or use the accessor method:

Code: (Objective-C) 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

The instance variables are now typically made private, meaning they're not accessible by subclasses directly by name.  So subclasses have no choice but to use the inherited accessor methods in order to access their values.  Remember, the synthesized methods may be doing additional work based on their attributes (e.g., retain, copy, nonatomic) that won't happen when assigning  or retrieving values directly to/from an instance variable.  So there's an extra level of abstraction between the property and the instance variable.

Comment: @synthesize window=_window

Comment: Why would somebody still use @synthesis if it's done automatically in modern clang?

Answer (score 0):

Because the property getter performs special functionality and is not merely returning `_window`:

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UIApplicationDelegate/window):

> Implementation of this property is required if your app’s Info.plist
>   file contains the UIMainStoryboardFile key. Fortunately, the Xcode
>   project templates usually include a synthesized declaration of the
>   property automatically for the app delegate. The default value of this
>   synthesized property is nil, which causes the app to create a generic
>   UIWindow object and assign it to the property. If you want to provide
>   a custom window for your app, you must implement the getter method of
>   this property and use it to create and return your custom window.